# django form wizard redirect

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-formwizard

I have a django form wizard. Before a user enters the wizard and at each of the 4 steps of the wizard, I want to evaluate an if condition to check for data.

When the if condition fails, I want to exit the wizard and redirect the user to the start page, where an info block is displayed telling the user of the issue of no data.

I have tried placing the if condition to redirect the user in the wizard, but I have been advised that I **can't return a redirect in get_context_data(), since the SessionWizardView won't return that value as a response**.

Is there a way around this issue?

Here is my form wizard code:

```
class CreateDocumentWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'documents/document_create.html'

    form_list = [
        core_forms.CreateDocumentWizardForm01,
        core_forms.CreateDocumentWizardForm02,
        core_forms.CreateDocumentWizardForm03,
        core_forms.CreateDocumentWizardForm04,
    ]

    def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
        kwargs = super(CreateDocumentWizard, self).get_form_kwargs(step)
        kwargs.setdefault('user', self.request.user)
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):

        name_details_count = NameDetails.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()

        # redirect user if no name details held.
        if name_details_count < 1:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('document_start')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.render) or even `get()/post()/dispatch()` methods:

```
class CreateDocumentWizard(SessionWizardView):

    ...

    def render(self, form=None, **kwargs):
        name_details_count = NameDetails.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()

        # redirect user if no name details held.
        if name_details_count < 1:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('document_start')

        return super(CreateDocumentWizard, self).render(form, **kwargs)
```

Comment: twil - a very big thank you! that code works a treat! Awesome!